# Resizing Window Vertically

Tags: awesome-wm

**EDIT: this question/answer is from 2013, back when Awesome was still on version 3.4/3.5, a lot has changed since then as Awesome was rewritten in version 4+ and what you see here may be different now. I'm adding this disclaimer because I'm seeing new responses/views for this question.**

I'm trying to map my awesome wm shortcuts similar to tmux. I like tmux's alt+arrow combination to resize the pane in either dimension. I'm aware that awesome's `awful.tag.incmwfact()` function will work vertically or horizontally depending on layout. However, I'd also like a function that resizes in the other dimension under the same layout as well. This would be useful for maximizing one of the smaller windows vertically without invading the space of the largest window on the other half of the screen:

```
+----------+----------+
|          |          |
|          |     ^    |
|          +-----|----+
|          |     v    |
|          |          |
+----------+----------+
```

I found the `awful.client.moveresize()` function as well, but it only seems to work in floating layout. I know this is doable since I can resize the windows with a mouse, even in tiling layouts. I just don't know which function the mouse hooks into.

Comment: I wonder if when they rewrote it, that this capability got taken out. I see this Q&A as well as tons of cheatsheets mentioning mod+L and mod+H purportedly providing this functionality. It looks like I've tried everything (btw mod+right mouse drag is also for resizing) and in tiled mode it looks to me like *all tiles* in a tiling layout are *static* in size. Very disappointing.

Comment: @StevenLu I could only get `awful.tag.incmwfact` to work on certain layouts (`awful.layout.layouts `). For example, it works with `awful.layout.suit.tile,` and `awful.layout.suit.tile.left,`, but it does not work on `awful.layout.suit.fair,`. I suppose that would make it unfair. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Figured it out, posting the answer for others who need this functionality as well:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Mod1"    }, "Right",     function () awful.tag.incmwfact( 0.01)    end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Mod1"    }, "Left",     function () awful.tag.incmwfact(-0.01)    end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Mod1"    }, "Down",     function () awful.client.incwfact( 0.01)    end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Mod1"    }, "Up",     function () awful.client.incwfact(-0.01)    end),
```

Basically, instead of tag's `incmwfact`, use the client's own `incwfact` function. Also, this will only work in tiling layouts, in floating it will cause an error bubble.

Answer (score 6):

With Awesome version 4, put the following in the `clientkeys` section of `rc.lua`.

To **move** windows with <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Down",   function (c) c:relative_move(  0,  20,   0,   0) end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Up",     function (c) c:relative_move(  0, -20,   0,   0) end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Left",   function (c) c:relative_move(-20,   0,   0,   0) end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Right",  function (c) c:relative_move( 20,   0,   0,   0) end),
```

To **resize** windows with <kbd>mod</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Next",   function (c) c:relative_move( 20,  20, -40, -40) end),
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "Prior",  function (c) c:relative_move(-20, -20,  40,  40) end),
```

Comment: the original question asks about window  resizing and your answer is about window movement, maybe that would be the reason for the downvote, still a useful answer for me. Thank you!.

Comment: @deadPoet: True, that could be the reason - however moving and resizing is closely related (it's even the same exact method to call in awesome wm), and half of my answer _is_ about resizing. :) Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: With the solution given by you I did solved resizing and moving issues,  as OP a suggest a different solution still can't find a good reason to downvote yours.

Answer (score 4):

Modkey + h or l resizes the tiling.

Comment: This only resizes the master window, not the slaves.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but can be helpful for newbies in awesome. To resize windows you can press:

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

or

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd>